# How to increment pointer in more than one way?

Tags: c

```
void squeeze(char s[], int c){
 int i, j;
     for (i = j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
         if (s[i] != c)
             s[j++] = s[i];
     s[j] = '\0';
 }
```

I am doing exercise 2-4 of the book K&R: "Exercise 2-4. Write an alternative version of squeeze(s1,s2) that deletes each character in s1 that matches any character in the string s2."
However I'm trying to implement it with pointers. Here is what I have:

```
void squeeze(char *p, char *y){
    for(; *p != '\0'; p++)
        if(*p != *y++)
            *p++ = *p;
    *p++ = '\0';
}
```

However it does not achieve the same thing that the `s[j++]` is doing in the first piece of code. What can I do to do what the `s[j++ ]` is doing, but with pointers instead of subscripting?

Comment: Why, how `int c` become `char *y`?

Comment: You need two pointers. `*(dst++) = *src;` Initially, `src` and `dst` are the same, but that changes as soon as you delete something. (This incidentally gets rid of the problem that you are both reading a var and writing to the same var without an intervening sequence point.)

Comment: `*p++ = *p;` is undefined behavior. `p` is modified and accessed at the same time.

Comment: @KamilCuk I am sending in two pointers of char arrays. The purpose of the program is to delete characters in the array that *p is pointing to that are in the array that *y is pointing to.

Comment: So it's doing something different then "the above code". "The above code" I believe removes all characters equal to `int c`. So you want to implement "the above code" or implement some other function? Och I see, that is similar. So instead of `if (s[i] != c)` you want to traverse `y` string to see if any bytes are equal to `s[i]`.

Comment: @KamilCuk That's right. Specifically this: Write an alternative version of squeeze(s1,s2) that deletes each character in s1 that matches any character in the string s2. This is exercise 2-4 of K&R

Comment: @Tom Karzes, Yeah, I misremembered and removed that from my comment after double-checking the op precedence table. Still, I'm always surprised that `*` doesn't bind the tighest, so parens don't hurt. It's just not a problem like I had originally stated

Comment: @Kyle Santiago, Your modified version doesn't even try to do that. It only looks a one character of `y` per loop pass, not each one.

Comment: @ikegami I would need to reverse the for loop right? Have the one that is nested be on top and the other nested in it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "reverse the for loop". You can't reverse the order in which you traverse through `s`, and the order in which you traverse through `y` is irrelevant. /// Yes, you will need nested loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You copy from a "source, to a "destination". It's easier with verbose names:

```
void squeeze2(char s[], int c){
   char *src = s, *dst = s;
   for (; *src != '\0'; src++) {
     if (*src != c) {
         *dst++ = *src;
     }
   }
   *dst = '\0';
}
```

> Write an alternative version of squeeze(s1,s2) that deletes each character in s1 that matches any character in the string s2.

Use `strchr` to find character in string.

```
void squeeze3(char s[], const char reject[]){
   char *src = s, *dst = s;
   for (; *src != '\0'; src++) {
     if (strchr(reject, *src) == NULL) {
         *dst++ = *src;
     }
   }
   *dst = '\0';
}
```

Out of training: a version without `strchr` that traverses the second string and checks if any character matches `*str`. If it does, it is not copied.

```
void squeeze4(char s[], const char reject[]){
    char *src = s, *dst = s;
    for (; *src != '\0'; src++) {

        const char *r;
        for (r = reject; *r != '\0'; ++r) {
            if (*src == *r) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (*r == '\0') {
            *dst++ = *src;
        }
   }
   *dst = '\0';
}
```

Comment: How would I do this with pointers however? If I send in two pointers to arrays like so: ```void squeeze(char *p, char *y)```, how can I achieve the same effect? *p is pointing to a char array and *y is pointing to the array that, if *p has the same chars, to delete from the array *p is pointing to.

Comment: The second code snippet does that. Maybe refresh the page, my edit could be not visible.

Comment: Both of them have a char sent in. However, I am trying to do it by just sending the pointers of the arrays and go through them to find if the first one has any character the second array contains, and delete them.

Comment: Literally `void squeeze3(char s[], const char reject[])` and `void squeeze4(char s[], const char reject[])` do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are both reading a var and changing that same var without an intervening sequence point. This is *Undefined Behaviour*.

But that's not it. `s[j++] = s[i];` accesses two unrelated elements of `s`, so two pointers will necessarily be needed if you eliminate the indexes, but you only have one. You need something like this:

```
*dst++ = *src;
```

This incidentally gets rid of the first problem I mentioned.

So, we get the following:

```
void squeeze(char *s, char c) {
    char *src = s;
    char *dst = s;
    for (; *src; ++src) {
         if (*src != c)
             *(dst++) = *src;
    }

    *dst = 0;
 }
```

Comment: This uses a char, but what if I wanted to send in both arrays by pointer and go through them to find if the first one has any character the second array contains, and delete them? As such:```void squeeze(char *p, char *y)```

Comment: Please don't ask new unrelated questions in the comments. If you have another question, ask another Question. But you're not going to learn anything if we do it for you! Tip: You will necessarily need to loop over the elements of the second array for each element of the first array.